# Objective-c string not working

Tags: objective-c, string

Hi Im new to Objective C and I have a question. So here is my code...

```
CCScene *restartScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Levels/Level%d",_currentLevel];
```

Basically when the level loads I want it to load what ever level the value of _currentLevel is, but I am getting an error saying "too many arguments to method call, expected 1,have 2". I am probably making a really noob mistake but thanks in advance.

Comment: [CCBReader loadAsScene:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Levels/Level%d",_currentLevel]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadAsScence needs a String as argument. So you have to construct a string:

```
CCScene *restartScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Levels/Level%d",_currentLevel];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I must have been doing something stupid. Sorry I can't vote up your comment I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `stringWithFormat:` to create a string using parameters...

```
NSString *sceneString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Levels/Level%d", _currentLevel];
CCScene *restartScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:sceneString];
```

You can not add parameters to a string without using a string creator of some sort.